# Scala generics: type mismatch with folding

Tags: scala, generics

New to scala. Trying to understand why scala compiler is not happy about the below:

```
sealed trait LinkedList[A] {
  def fold[B](end: B)(func: (A, B) => B): B =
    this match {
      case End() => end
      case Pair(hd, tl) => func(hd, tl.fold(end)(func))
    }

  def sum: Int =
    fold[Int](0){(hd, tl) => hd + tl}
}

final case class Pair[A](head: A, tail: LinkedList[A]) extends LinkedList[A]
final case class End[A]() extends LinkedList[A]

object Foo extends App {
  val example = Pair(1, Pair(2, Pair(3, End())))
  println(example.sum)
}
```

Getting this error:

```
Error:(10, 35) type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: String
    fold[Int](0){(hd, tl) => hd + tl}
```

How is String being inferred here?

Please help.

Comment: + is not defined on your type A  you can use duck typing for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a general `A`, usual "addition" is not defined. So instead, it implicitly converts `A` into `String`, and uses the `+` that concatenates `String`s. A quick and dirty workaround would be:

```
def sum(implicit i: A =:= Int): Int = fold[Int](0){(hd, tl) => i(hd) + tl}
```

This would make `sum` available only if `A` is `Int`. A somewhat more systematic approach would be to use `Numeric` typeclass, just like the method in the [standard library](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#sum:A) (unfold "use case" and "Full signature").